# Play Framework client server exception handling

Tags: scala, playframework

I am new to play framework. I am using *`Play Framework (2.4)`* with *`scala`*. I need your opinion about exception handling.

Our play client controller is calling play server controller. Now we need to introduce custom exceptions which will be thrown from Server and client will catch that exception and do necessary things.

Now when I throw any exception from server it is not reaching client as it is. The reason I found behind this is, Play catches all exceptions and convert them to `500 Internal Server Error`

So is it possible to send custom exception to client without modifying it?

Comment: Client controller invoking server controller method directly via reverse routing? Like `controllers.routes.ServerController.someServerMethod()`.

Comment: Not sure what is reverse routing but we are not calling server this way. We are invoking server URL and passing parameters in URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop play from giving `500` by handling the exception by yourself in the play controller

You can write a custom action builder for this purpose

```
object ExceptionCatchingAction extends ActionBuilder[Request] {
    override def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (Request[A]) => Future[Result]): Future[Result] = {
      block(request).recover { case th =>
        //use meaningful http codes instead of OK here based on the exception type
        Ok(Json.obj("msg" -> "error occurred", "info" -> "error info"))
      }
    }
  }
```

Use it like this

```
object ExampleController extends Controller {
    def doStuff = ExceptionCatchingAction { req =>
      throw new Exception("foo")
    }
  }
```

Your client will no get all the exceptions. So that client can now take decisions on what to do.

Comment: It's a bad habit to respond `Ok` with an error, you should use more meaningful http error codes.

Comment: @vdebergue ... ur right . added the info to the answer

Comment: I am getting compilation error on "Ok(Json.obj("msg" -> "error occurred", "info" -> "error info"))" line saying 'Expression of type Result doesn't conform to expected type _U'

Comment: @YogeshPatil  ... code in the answer compiles and is tested

Comment: What is Play framework version you are using? I am using v2.4

Comment: @YogeshPatil action builder is same in v2.4 also

Comment: @pamu thanks its working there small mistake i was doing.